# Installing lightgbm in R

Tags: r, github, package

I have tried different things to install the `lightgbm` package but I can´t get it done. I tried all methods at the [github repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/R-package) but they don't work.
I run Windows 10 and R 3.5 (64 bit). There is [someone](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/912) with similar problems. So I tried his solution:

- 1. Installing cmake (64bit)
- 2. Installing Visual Studio (2017)
- 3. Installing Rtools (64bit)
- 4. Changing Path in the System Variables to "C:\Program 
     Files\CMake\bin\cmake;"
- 5. Installing lightgbm with Precompiled dll/lib

-->

```
  devtools::install_github("Laurae2/lgbdl", force = TRUE)
  library(lgbdl)
  lgb.dl(commit = "master",
  compiler = "vs",
  repo = "https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM")

 *** arch - i386
installing via 'install.libs.R' to C:/Users/X1/Documents/R/win- 
library/3.5/lightgbm
Error in eval(ei, envir) : Cannot find lib_lightgbm.dll
* removing 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/lightgbm'
In R CMD INSTALL
installation of package 
�C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpczNLaN/LightGBM/R-package� had non- 
zero exit status[1] FALSE
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me, hope it helps.

1. Make sure you install all mandatory software
2. Download the precomplied .dll file from https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/releases
   and put it in .\LightGBM\
3. In install.libs.R, set use_precompile <- TRUE
4. Copy CMakeLists.txt from root directory into .\LightGBM\R-package\inst\bin
5. In R console type: 
   install.packages(file.path("C:\yourdirectory\", "LightGBM", "R-package"), repos = NULL, type = "source")

Answer (score 3):

For some poor soul struggling through this and if the above mentioned fixes did not work.  What I had to do to get it working was:

- Ensure you have the following in your path environment variables:

  - Rtools (point to the bin folder in the install directory of rtools)
  - Rtools mingw_64 (point to the mingw_64 folder in the rtools install
    directory)
  - Base R (point to the bin folder in your base R install directory,
    i.e. where you install R version whatever)
  - CMake (point to the bin folder in your cmake install directory)
  - Visual Studio (allows you to build with VS Build Tools, otherwise will fallback to RTools or any MinGW64 available as stated on the github page)
  - Git
- Before installing LightGBM, install the following packages in R
  itself:

  - data.tools
  - magrittr
  - R6
  - jsonlite
- Once all the above is done, run with the git installation
  instructions as on the github page [here](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/R-package)

  For those not able to access the link (or if it should move), the
  command are the following:

  ```
  git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM

  cd LightGBM

  Rscript build_r.R
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to install it after a "million" tries. I had to ensure there was only one R version installed - 64 bit and that all the other steps were done with the expected environmental variables set.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run LightGBM in R, but you are not a software engineer... then, you can use R and Python (because it is a pain to install the R package).

First, write this in your R console or R Markdown:

```
library(reticulate)
library(knitr)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python3 = reticulate::eng_python)
```

Second, write this in your R console or R Markdown:

```
Sys.which("python3")
os = import("os")
os$listdir(".")
```

Third, open your notepad, save it as "script.py", code your functions and call the appropriate libraries. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb

def python_to_r_lgbm(X_train, y_train, X_test):
    lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train)

    params = {'bagging_fraction': 0.75, 
              'boosting_type': 'gbdt', 
              'drop_rate': 0.15, 
              'feature_fraction': 1, 
              'lambda_l1': 2.95, 
              'lambda_l2': 2.35, 
              'learning_rate': 0.01, 
              'max_depth': 3, 'max_leaves': 19, 
              'min_data_in_leaf': 8, 
              'objective': 'regression', 
              'metrics': ['l1', 'l2', 'huber'], 
              'verbose': -1}

    gbm = lgb.train(params, lgb_train, 1800)

    light_gbm_test = gbm.predict(X_test)

    return light_gbm_test
```

Then, run this in your R console or R Markdown:

```
source_python('script.py')
```

Finally, call it in your R console (or R Markdown) your new function:

```
python_to_r_lgbm(xTrain_df, y_train, xTest_df)
```

This function will train your model with the xTrain_df and y_train and will give you the predictions using xTest_df.

*Make sure to have all the files in the same folder. Also, make sure to have Python3 (obviously) and the lightgbm library installed (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/lightgbm).

Jokes aside, I hope this helps you. I also hope not to be lynch by an angry mob because I did not answer the question directly :D

The source: https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/03/18/the-reticulate-package-solves-the-hardest-problem-in-data-science-people/
Although I did some modifications.